# how to implement passwordless authentication in identityserver3

Tags: identityserver3

I'm looking for the correct way to customize or extend identityserver3 to implement passwordless authentication.

the user scenario is

- user uses browser to go to website
- website detects non-authenticated
  user and redirects to idsrv3 instance
- idsrv3 asks for email address (or uses a cookie stored one) and if email address matches a known user, sends an email with a link (e.g. like the registration or password reset link)
- user clicks on link
- idsrv3 instance checks if token in link matches a known user and is not expired
- idsrv3 issues token
- idsrv3 redirects to original url

after some reading, I think the correct way to customize idsrv3 would be to

- create a custom viewservice

  - checks the emailaddress
  - generates and stores a token in the user account record
  - sends an email with a link consisting of a custom grant, the token and a returnurl
- create a custom grant and corresponding validator

  - checks the incoming token and if valid returns a positive validation result linked to a user account
- the normal idsrv3 token issuing flow takes over to issue a token and redirect to the returnurl

In my experience, idsrv3 is great, but it can be time-consuming to get things right when customizing and I would like to be sure that I don't hit a brick wall somewhere near the end of the solution.

Comment: I am in a similar situation - I don't want the user to enter their credentials. What you plan to do is perfectly doable, but I am not sure if its completely secure and tamper free. Alternatively I have also been exploring ways to issue **short lived user certificates** and authenticate users based on that, instead of credentials based login. Still evaluating this. Negatives: Large number of self-signed private certificates required to be issued and managed, and probably performance due to additional validations. I cant find any authentic Thinktecure documentation about this though.